# When or why is equals not the opposite of not equals in a SQL query?

Tags: sql, oracle, toad

In a table containing five records where the Toppings value is "Chocolate", two of them have the value "Yes" in the MaraschinoCherry column, the other three contain nothing in that column (not "No" - nothing/blank).

This query works fine:

```
select definition from desserts 
where (Toppings = 'Chocolate') and 
      (MaraschinoCherry <> 'Yes') 
order by id
```

...returning the expected three records; but this one returns nothing at all, rather than the two records I expect:

```
select definition from desserts 
where (Toppings = 'Chocolate') and 
      (MaraschinoCherry = 'Yes') 
order by id
```

???

Comment: Double check the records that have the value 'Yes'. Perhaps there are some spaces around it? Try running the same query with `LIKE '%Yes%'` to ensure the same.

Comment: Are you sure the 2 have 'Yes' not 'Yes ' or worse? Try with a trim.

Comment: What is the datatype of MaraschinoCherry?  If it is only Yes/No, you should make it a boolean, and store TRUE or FALSE instead.

Comment: Supply the create table and insert statements to populate the table.

Comment: an empty column is interpreted as NULL.   That may have an effect on what is going on.

Comment: @SableFoste - Oracle doesn't have a native boolean type. A column constrained to two possible values is the closest you can get.

Comment: @EvilTeach: I also tried "is null" but that also failed.

Comment: @EvilTeach: the table and column names have been changed, so the create table DDL wouldn't be valid.

Comment: run this: select * from desserts where MaraschinoCherry not in ('Yes');  nulls won't be returned, and if you see any that look like 'Yes' then something else (space or binary char) is in there.

Comment: Does your data look something like [this SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/9c60a/5)?

Comment: @ClayShannon Please post some sample create and insert statements - if the problem truly is with the `= 'Yes'` not working then it's not likely it's a `NULL` issue but instead something wrong with the data.

Comment: @Mikael: That gives me, "Sorry, cannot not display report: unkown report type" - "cannot not" should mean that it can, but it still can't.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The answer to your question is simple.  Any comparison to a NULL value, with two exceptions, produces NULL as the result.  So,

```
MaraschinoCherry = 'Yes'
```

and

```
MaraschinoCherry <> 'Yes'
```

*Both* return NULL when MaraschinoCherry has a NULL value.  NULL comparisons are treated the same as FALSE.

The two exceptions are:  IS NULL and IS NOT NULL.  Note that "= NULL" always returns NULL, which is interpreted as FALSE.

The normal way to fix this is by using COALESCE:

```
COALESCE(MaraschinoCherry, 'NO') = 'Yes'
```

(The function ISNULL() is kind of equivalent, but COALESCE allows more arguments and is standard SQL.)

There are other ways you can fix this, such as by specifying a default value for the column when you define the table, by adding an explicit comparison to NULL, by declaring the column to be "NOT NULL", or in some databases by overriding the behavior of NULLs in comparisons to violate the SQL standards (HIGHLY NOT RECOMMENDED!).

Comment: I'm missing something... if `MaraschinoCherry` is either `'Yes'` or `null`, then the first query finds nothing - because of the null comparison behaviour you describe, `null <> 'Yes'` is false - and the second finds two records. How do you get from there to three from the first and none from the second?